# Point an array to another array from a function

Tags: java, arrays

I have a question about editing arrays:

If I call a function that edits the elements of the array, for example doubles all the values, I know that it's not necessary to return the new, edited array from the function because when calling the function I don't pass the array itself, but the memory adress. So, when the function edits the array, it edits the origin:

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    int[] myArray = {1, 2, 3};

    // myArray is now {1, 2, 3}
    arrayDouble(myArray);
    // myArray is now {2, 4, 6}, exactly what I want
}

public static void arrayDouble(int[] arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        arr[i] *= 2;
}
```

But what if I have a dynamic array, that increases and decreases in size whenever the user adds/deletes records. Lets say that I have a function that resets the array to size 0. Is it possible to reset the origin array without a return function, the same way as above?

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    int[] myArray = {1, 2, 3};

    // myArray is now {1, 2, 3}
    arrayReset(myArray);
    // myArray is still {1, 2, 3}. Here I want myArray to be {0}
}

public static void arrayReset(int[] arr)
{
    int[] newArr = new int[0];

    arr = newArr;
}
```

Currently I've solved the problem this way, but I think it looks ugly and unclean:

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    int[] myArray = {1, 2, 3};

    // myArray is now {1, 2, 3}
    myArray = arrayReset(myArray); // I assign the return value to my array
    // myArray is now {0}, just as I want
}

public static int[] arrayReset(int[] arr)
{
    int[] newArr = new int[1];

    return newArr;
}
```

Comment: just so you know, the `Main` in your function should be a `main`

Comment: That looks quite clean actually, and what you're looking for is the `java.util.ArrayList` class

Comment: As a heads up, java arrays have a **fixed** `length`. They cannot grow or shrink in size. As @MadPhysicist said, you want an `ArrayList`.

Comment: @null_awe sry, that's a typo.

Comment: @MadPhysicist @ElliottFrisch I quess the answer is "no" then =) I'll take a look at `ArrayList`. Thanks guys!

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you should follow a best practices.

Best practice is **not change input elements of the method**, i.e. you method should not change input array and always create a new one. So your `ugly` solution is the very most correct one.

```
public static int[] arrayReset(int[] arr) {
    int[] res = new int[1];
    // ...
    return res;
}
```

Sure, you can modify the given array, e.g. if you do not want/cant crate a new copy of the array. In this case you do not have to retrieve an array (but you can), because as you correctly mentioned, the client already has the reference to this array. Following snippets are equals:

```
public static void arrayReset(int[] arr) {
    // ...
}

public static int[] arrayReset(int[] arr) {
    // ...
    return arr;
}
```

And finaly. The array in `java` is immutable object (I mean you cannot change the size of it). If you really want it, you have to use either `List<>` or `array wrapper`.

```
public static void arrayReset(List<Integer> arr) {
    arr.clear();
}


int[] arr = new int[3];
int[][] wrapper = {arr};
arrayReset(wrapper);
arr = wrapper[0];

// wrapper[0] contains an original array
public static void arrayReset(int[][] wrapper) {
    int[] arr = arrWrapper[0];
    arr = new int[1]; // change array size
    // do smth
    wrapper[0] = arr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks oleg! The wrapper idea was really clever! =D